# React native i cannot add a new screen without adding it to createMaterialBottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Hello i want to be able to go to a new page without adding them to <Tab.Screen by another meaning i want to use this.props.navigation.navigate so in order for me to do that i need to add the new screen but how i can add a new screen without adding them to <tab.screen

this is a small sample of my code

```
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" shifting={true}>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Feed"
          component={mainPage}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: 'Home',
            tabBarColor: '#29a8ab',

            tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
              <Icon name="home" color={color} size={26} />
            ),
          }}
          tabBarColor={'#FF0000'}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Notifications"
          component={cartPage}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: 'Shop',

            tabBarColor: '#ff8b94',
            tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
              <Icon name="cart" color={color} size={26} />
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default createApp;
```

Comment: Check here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/

Comment: thank you and btw i checked it yesterday it didn't work but when i try it today it worked anyway thank you.